# interface and generics C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a interface like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> where T:class
    {

        long OS { get; set; }

        T App { get; set; }
    }
```

and another interface like this:

```
public interface IMyInterfaces
    {
        List<IMyInterface<T>> Subscribers { get; set; } //this line give me error
    }
```

I got error

Comment: attention that, i want a list of any type of T

Comment: You need to define T also in IMyInterfaces

Comment: if i define T, i lose my list that can store any type of IMyInterface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a concrete type or another generic parameter for `T` when you use `IMyInterface<T>`

```
public interface IMyInterfaces
{
    List<IMyInterface<int>> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```

OR

```
public interface IMyInterfaces<TOther>
{
    List<IMyInterface<TOther>> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```

**Note** I used `TOther` to stress that it is another generic parameter, different from the `T` in `IMyInterface` but you could use the same name (`T`) for `TOther`

Comment: You mean there is no way to, i have a list of interface<T> that interface<T> may be any type?

Comment: You could use `IMyInterface<object>`, and anything can be cast to object.

Comment: Then no, you either make `IMyInterfaces` generic as well or you specify a concrete  generic parameter for `IMyInterface`. There is no way to declare something with a free generic type parameter